# read text file from url in java for android

Tags: android, arrays, url, text

I want to read a simple text file into an array row by row. I can not read this file into an array.
No matter what I do it just does not work for me.

```
String myUrlTextFile = "www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/pocket.txt";

try 
{
    URL myText= new URL(myUrlTextFile);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(myText.openStream());

    while (s.next() != null) 
    {
         mylistArray.add(s.next());
    }


    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
catch(IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what does you logcat output look like?

Comment: @Dany Maor.. Which version of `Android` are you trying this code?

Comment: Do you have internet permission in your manifest? and can you access this file from your device? Browser?

Comment: I use Android 4. and my manifest I add this code :     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: my logcat - http://www.kidzy.org/log.txt

Answer (score 0):

You require the protocol specifier i.e "http://" at the start of your URL

**UPDATE**

From honeycomb onwards, network operations on the main thread are block.

The clue here is in the logcat output:

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Use an AsynchTask or other threading method to keep network activity on subordinate threads.

Comment: you need to run this using a separate thread, the easiest way is to use an AsynchTask to retrieve your file.  The line in your logcat that indicates this is `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`